# How many open-backends does IO::File use?

Tags: perl, file-io

Is the built-in `open` function, the basic Perl open operator and the three-argument open operator` described in [IO::File#METHODS](http://perldoc.perl.org/IO/File.html#METHODS) all the same function?

Comment: The list operators like `open` are often called functions. In fact, they are documented in "perlfunc".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no.

The `open` built-in is described in [`perldoc -f open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). This function is well suited to do actual, text-oriented work. It can use PerlIO-layers, to do automatic de- or encoding of the input stream.

Perl has another way to open files, called [`sysopen`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysopen.html). This is essentially a very thin wrapper around C's `fdopen`, with all gotchas and issues. In Perl, `sysopen` is called like

```
sysopen FILEHANDLE, FILENAME, MODE[, PERMS]
```

Now, [`IO::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/IO%3a%3aFile) provides an object-oriented interface for opening files, and inherits from `IO::Handle`. The `open` *method* contains the following [code](https://metacpan.org/source/GBARR/IO-1.25/lib/IO/File.pm):

```
sub open {
  @_ >= 2 && @_ <= 4 or croak 'usage: $fh->open(FILENAME [,MODE [,PERMS]])';
  my ($fh, $file) = @_;
  if (@_ > 2) {
    my ($mode, $perms) = @_[2, 3];
    if ($mode =~ /^\d+$/) {
      defined $perms or $perms = 0666;
      return sysopen($fh, $file, $mode, $perms);
    } elsif ($mode =~ /:/) {
      return open($fh, $mode, $file) if @_ == 3;
      croak 'usage: $fh->open(FILENAME, IOLAYERS)';
    } else {
      return open($fh, IO::Handle::_open_mode_string($mode), $file);
    }
  }
  open($fh, $file);
}
```

As you can see, it is a wrapper around `open` and `sysopen`, so it is safe to say that this method is not identical to the core `open` ;-) Also, the doc (to which you linked) says so.